# 3 Confusing MySQL Warnings

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I'm sorry if the title isn't clear enough (I find it hard to explain what I'm dealing with, and English isn't my native language).

These two scripts cause three warnings:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/username/public_html/xxx/libraries/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php
>   on line 227
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/username/public_html/xxx/include/config.php on line 140
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be
>   established in /home/username/public_html/xxx/include/config.php on
>   line 140

**The Config PHP**

```
    if($sban != "1")
{
    $bquery = "SELECT count(*) as total from bans_ips WHERE ip='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'";
    $bresult = $conn->execute($bquery);
    $bcount = $bresult->fields['total'];
    if($bcount > "0")
    {
        $brdr = $config['baseurl']."/banned.php";
        header("Location:$brdr");
        exit;
    }
}
```

**The adodb-mysql.inc.php**

```
function _pconnect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword, $argDatabasename)
    {
        if (ADODB_PHPVER >= 0x4300)
            $this->_connectionID = mysql_pconnect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,$this->clientFlags);
        else
            $this->_connectionID = mysql_pconnect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword);
        if ($this->_connectionID === false) return false;
        if ($this->autoRollback) $this->RollbackTrans();
        if ($argDatabasename) return $this->SelectDB($argDatabasename);
        return true;    
    }
```

What I don't understand is that there's no error whether using localhost or my other hosting (I have 2 hosting services and only one that works well).

Please, could you kindly suggest to me what to do in a very newbie way?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_real_escape_string` in this manner. This looks like either PDO or `mysqli`, so you should use the [SQL placeholder system](http://bobby-tables.com/php) available to those.

Comment: Hello. Are you running this from a free or webserver? Some may disable access of MySQL. "mysql_pconnect() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: You might have to call your hosting that doesn't work.  I believe you're getting those two second errors because of the first error.  You will have to talk to your hosting company about using `mysql_pconnect()`

Comment: Where does this `_pconnect` method come from? Is this a framework?

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_query` subsystem requires an active connection to be defined before the escaping function will work, but don't bother fixing this. Instead use the database library you're employing correctly.

It's not clear which you're using from this short example, the connection code is omitted.

The PDO [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function can bind values, and the `mysqli` [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method is similar. Both completely replace `mysql_real_escape_string`.